# How to do a relation between two maps with a Object key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 2 maps:

```
Map<KeyMapMediciones,ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard> medicionesMap =
   new HashMap<KeyMapMediciones,ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard>();

Map<KeyMapMediciones, ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard> medicionesAplicacionMap =
   new HashMap<KeyMapMediciones,ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard>();
```

The bean `KeyMapMediciones` has 3 attributes:

```
private int tipoTransaccion;
private String canal;
private String aplicacion;
```

I need to create a relationship between the two maps where the `KeyMapMediciones.canal` = `KeyMapMediciones.aplicacion` in the other map.

For each `aplicacion` I need to get n `canal`.

Comment: Didn't get what you want in result. List of all `KeyMapMediciones` which have  `aplicacion` equal to `canal`?

Comment: Do the keys of the first map always have `aplicacion == null` and the keys of the second map always have `canal == null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to guess what you are looking for. I made this presumptions:

- in `medicionesMap` you always have `canal != null` and `aplicacion == null`
- in `medicionesAplicacionMap` you always have `canal == null` and `aplicacion != null`
- there is a **1:1** relationship between `canal` and `aplication`

I would recommend to rethink your datastructure. I would suggest something like this:

```
/** superclass for medicions */
abstract class Medicion {
    public int tipoTransaccion;
    public ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard standard;
}

/** those medicions with canals, referencing medicions with aplicacions */
class MedicionCanal extends Medicion {
    public String canal;
    public MedicionAplicacion medicionAplicacion;
}

/** those medicions with aplicacions */
class MedicionAplicacion extends Medicion {
    public String aplicacion;
}
```

You can easily fill that new classes by using your existing data:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

/** old structure */
class KeyMapMediciones {
    public int tipoTransaccion;
    public String canal;
    public String aplicacion;
}

class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<KeyMapMediciones,ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard> medicionesMap =
                new HashMap<KeyMapMediciones,ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard>();

        Map<KeyMapMediciones, ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard> medicionesAplicacionMap =
                new HashMap<KeyMapMediciones,ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard>();

        // create map of aplicacion to Medicion by second map
        Map<String, MedicionAplicacion> aplicacions = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<KeyMapMediciones, ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard> entry : medicionesAplicacionMap.entrySet()) {
            KeyMapMediciones key = entry.getKey();
            ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard value = entry.getValue();

            // copy data from old structure into new Medicion
            MedicionAplicacion medicionAplicacion = new MedicionAplicacion();
            medicionAplicacion.tipoTransaccion = key.tipoTransaccion;
            medicionAplicacion.aplicacion = key.aplicacion;
            medicionAplicacion.standard = value;

            aplicacions.put(medicionAplicacion.aplicacion, medicionAplicacion);
        }

        // create map of canal to Medicion by second map
        Map<String, MedicionCanal> canals = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<KeyMapMediciones,ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard> entry : medicionesMap.entrySet()) {
            KeyMapMediciones key = entry.getKey();
            ResultadoConsultaNegocioStandard value = entry.getValue();

            // copy data from old structure into new Medicion
            MedicionCanal medicionCanal = new MedicionCanal();
            medicionCanal.tipoTransaccion = key.tipoTransaccion;
            medicionCanal.canal = key.canal;
            medicionCanal.standard = value;

            // link to aplication
            medicionCanal.medicionAplicacion = aplicacions.get(key.canal);

            canals.put(medicionCanal.canal, medicionCanal);
        }

    }
}
```

Afterwards you can use these object references to query and reuse your data:

```
// find out the aplication of the medicion with canal == "canalA"
String aplicacionOfCanalA = canals.get("canalA").medicionAplicacion.aplicacion;
```